# Rendering a dictionary in a template

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates

While rendering values of a dictionary in a template, some values are showed outside the html table. I cant realize why.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

#This is how the dictionary is printed in console
[{'socio': 'Randazzo Walter Ariel 25', 'enero': 'P', 'febrero': 'P', 'marzo': 'P', 'abril': 'P', 'mayo': 'P', 'junio': 'P', 'julio': 'P', 'agosto': 'P', 'septiembre': 'P', 'octubre': 'P', 'noviembre': 'P', 'diciembre': 'P'}, {'socio': 'Silvi Edgardo Marcelo 31', 'enero': 'P', 'febrero': 'P', 'marzo': 'P', 'abril': 'P', 'mayo': 'P', 'junio': 'P', 'julio': '-', 'agosto': '-', 'septiembre': '-', 'octubre': '-', 'noviembre': '-', 'diciembre': '-'}]

#this is how the template is rendered
[image]

#Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Listados</title>
<style>

    * {
        color: black;
    }

    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: black;
    }

    .name-company {
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
    }

    table thead tr th {
        border: 1px solid black !important;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    table tbody tr td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    .img-logo {
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="{{ icon }}" width="140" height="32" style="text-align: right;">
<p style="text-align: right;margin-top: 2px;">
</p>
<br>
<p style="text-align: left;margin-top: 2px;">
Año: {{ano}}
</p>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <th style="width: 30%; text-align: center;">SOCIO</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">ENE</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">FEB</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">MAR</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">ABR</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">MAY</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">JUN</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">JUL</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">AGO</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">SEP</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">OCT</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">NOV</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">DIC</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for pago in pagos %}
        <tr {% if forloop.first %}style="padding-top: 3px;" {% endif %}>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.socio }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.enero }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.febrero }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.marzo }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.abril }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.mayo }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.junio }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.julio }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.agosto }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.septiembre }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.octubre }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.noviembre }}</td>
           <td class="text-center">{{ pago.diciembre }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#view

```
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    anolistado = self.kwargs['ano']
    listainfopagosanual=[]
    sociosdet=[]
    #devuelve el numero de socio
    def numerodesocio(soc):
        nrosocio=""
        for c in soc:
            if c.isnumeric():
                nrosocio+=c
        return nrosocio
    #Lista de socios con pagos
    pagosdet=PagosDetail.objects.all().select_related('pago').filter( ano_pago=anolistado).order_by('pago__numero_socio__numero_socio')
    for det in pagosdet:
        if str(det.pago.numero_socio) not in sociosdet:
            sociosdet.append(str(det.pago.numero_socio))
    #Por cada socio guardo los meses pagos
    for soc in sociosdet:
        nrosocio=numerodesocio(soc)
        pagosdet1=PagosDetail.objects.all().select_related('pago').filter( ano_pago=anolistado,pago__numero_socio=nrosocio)
        EneroPago="-";FebreroPago="-";MarzoPago="-";AbrilPago="-";MayoPago="-";JunioPago="-";JulioPago="-";AgostoPago="-";SeptiembrePago="-";OctubrePago="-";NoviembrePago="-";DiciembrePago="-"
        for det in pagosdet1:
            mespago=str(det.mes_pago)
            if mespago=="Enero":
                EneroPago="P"
            if mespago=="Febrero":
                FebreroPago="P"
            if mespago=="Marzo":
                MarzoPago="P"
            if mespago=="Abril":
                AbrilPago="P"
            if mespago=="Mayo":
                MayoPago="P"
            if mespago=="Junio":
                JunioPago="P"
            if mespago=="Julio":
                JulioPago="P"
            if mespago=="Agosto":
                AgostoPago="P"
            if mespago=="Septiembre":
                SeptiembrePago="P"
            if mespago=="Octubre":
                OctubrePago="P"
            if mespago=="Noviembre":
                NoviembrePago="P"
            if mespago=="Diciembre":
                DiciembrePago="P"
        listainfopagosanual.append({'socio':soc,'enero':EneroPago,'febrero':FebreroPago,'marzo':MarzoPago,'abril':AbrilPago,'mayo':MayoPago,'junio':JunioPago,'julio':JulioPago,'agosto':AgostoPago,'septiembre':SeptiembrePago,'octubre':OctubrePago,'noviembre':NoviembrePago,'diciembre':DiciembrePago})
    print (listainfopagosanual)
    try:
        template= get_template('socios/invoice_socioscuotas_anual.html')
        context={
        'ano': anolistado,
        'pagos': listainfopagosanual,
        'icon': '{}{}'.format(settings.STATIC_URL,'core/img/adicrareng.jpg'),           
        }
        html=template.render(context)
        response= HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        pisaStatus=pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response,link_callback=self.link_callback)
        return response
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return HttpResponse(reverse_lazy('pagos:list'))
```

#Models

```
class Socios(models.Model):
    numero_socio = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tipo_documento = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=tipos_documento, default ='DNI')
    documento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    nacionalidad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=lista_status,default='Activo')
    domicilio = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    localidad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=lista_provincia, default ='2')
    codigo_postal = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefono_fijo = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    fecha_ingreso = models.DateField(default=datetime.now,null=False,blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    institucion = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)

class PagosHead(models.Model):
    numero_pago = models.IntegerField()
    numero_socio = models.ForeignKey(Socios, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_pago = models.DateField(default=datetime.now,null=True,blank=True)
    importe_pago_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    observaciones_pago = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    numero_factura=models.CharField(max_length=14,default="00000-00000000",null=True,blank=True)

class PagosDetail(models.Model):
    pago=models.ForeignKey(PagosHead,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    importe_pago = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    mes_pago = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ano_pago = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
```

#Final Rendered html Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Listados</title>
<style>

    * {
        color: black;
    }

    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: black;
    }

    .name-company {
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
    }

    table thead tr th {
        border: 1px solid black !important;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    table tbody tr td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    .img-logo {
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="/static/core/img/adicrareng.jpg" width="140" height="32" style="text- 
 align: right;">
<p style="text-align: right;margin-top: 2px;">
</p>
<br>
<p style="text-align: left;margin-top: 2px;">
Año: 2020
</p>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <th style="width: 30%; text-align: center;">SOCIO</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">ENE</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">FEB</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">MAR</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">ABR</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">MAY</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">JUN</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">JUL</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">AGO</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">SEP</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">OCT</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">NOV</th>
        <th style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">DIC</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr style="padding-top: 3px;" >
           <td class="text-center">Randazzo Walter Ariel 25</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
        </tr>

        <tr >
           <td class="text-center">Silvi Edgardo Marcelo 31</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">P</td>
           <td class="text-center">-</td>
           <td class="text-center">-</td>
           <td class="text-center">-</td>
           <td class="text-center">-</td>
           <td class="text-center">-</td>
           <td class="text-center">-</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add the final rendered html code of the table too?

Comment: Hi yedpodtrzitko! i added the full html code. Thanks.

Comment: that is template, not the final rendered html code. The code in browser when you made the screenshot.

Comment: Gotcha yedpodtrzitko ! Updated

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a the structure of the data from list of dictionaries to a dictionary.

#Now This is how the dictionary is printed in console

```
{'25': {'socio': 'Randazzo Walter Ariel 25', 'enero': 'P', 'febrero': 'P', 'marzo': 'P', 'abril': 'P', 'mayo': 'P', 'junio': 'P', 'julio': 'P', 'agosto': 'P', 'septiembre': 'P', 'octubre': 'P', 'noviembre': 'P', 'diciembre': 'P'}, '31': {'socio': 'Silvi Edgardo Marcelo 31', 'enero': 'P', 'febrero': 'P', 'marzo': 'P', 'abril': 'P', 'mayo': 'P', 'junio': 'P', 'julio': '-', 'agosto': '-', 'septiembre': '-', 'octubre': '-', 'noviembre': '-', 'diciembre': '-'}}
```

This is how I populate the dictionary:

```
            dictinfopagosanual[nrosocio]={'socio':soc,
                                       'enero':EneroPago,
                                       'febrero':FebreroPago,
                                       'marzo':MarzoPago,
                                       'abril':AbrilPago,
                                       'mayo':MayoPago,
                                       'junio':JunioPago,
                                       'julio':JulioPago,
                                       'agosto':AgostoPago,
                                       'septiembre':SeptiembrePago,
                                       'octubre':OctubrePago,
                                       'noviembre':NoviembrePago,
                                       'diciembre':DiciembrePago,
        }
```

Then I render in the template as follow:

```
        <tbody>
    {% for key,value in pagos.items %}
        <tr {% if forloop.first %}style="padding-top: 3px;" {% endif %}>
        {% for key,value in value.items %}
           <td class="text-center">{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: so is it solved then or do you still have the problem? I copy-pasted the html you added and it renders correctly to me.

Comment: Hi yedpodtrzitko, its solved now. But I can't vote for my own post as the best result in order to mark it solved.